# Could not load type 'PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler' from assembly 'PayPal_Merchant_SDK'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal mobile checkout into a mobile web app, developed using mvc4, for some reason, when I try to use the function SetMobileExpressCheckout(xxx), I am getting the above error.

I have added the web.config entry across from the sdk example, and have added the reference to the 2 dlls that come with the SDK, but it still crashes, the full error message is below :

{"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for paypal: Could not load type 'PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler' from assembly 'PayPal_Merchant_SDK'. (C:\Projects\Mobile Development\Print Management\Print Management\web.config line 8)"}

so looking at this, it is pointing to the entry in the web config file,  which is added below, I have also created a new project with an empty site, added a page, and all the web.config entries etc, and it works fine.

Could it be something to do with mvc4 ??

I know the web.config entry is large, but I thought I would put it all in there incase it is something else in there causing the problem.

any help would be much appreciated, as I am very close to having this finished, but I just cant seem to find what the issue is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal_Merchant_SDK"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Print Management-20130104084836;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <!-- The URL that the user must be redirected to in order to login and approve some payment actions-->
      <add name="paypalUrl" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr"/>
      <!-- The API endpoint -->
      <add name="endpoint" value="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0"/>
      <!-- Connection timeout in milliseconds -->
      <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
      <!-- The number of times a request must be retried if the API endpoint is   unresponsive -->
      <add name="requestRetries" value="3"/>
      <add name="binding" value="SOAP"/>
      <add name="IPAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/>
      <!-- 
      API version number. You will not normally have to change this unless you
      have a specific need to work with an older version of the API
     -->
      <add name="APIVersion" value="96.0"/>
    </settings>
    <accounts>
      <!--
      Add API credentials - 3 token or client certificate.
      You can add multiple account credentials here. The SDK will pick the first   account
      unless you specifically request an account in the service wrapper mehod.
    -->
      <account apiUsername="emailaddress" apiPassword="validpassword" apiSignature="signature" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T" certificateSubject="" signatureSubject=""/>
      <!--
    <account apiUsername="enduser_biz_api1.gmail.com" apiPassword="SACH3VA3C29DXGUG"
      apiCertificate="<Absolute path to paypal_cert.p12>" 
             privateKeyPassword="password" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T"/>
     -->
    </accounts>
  </paypal>
  <!-- Configure logging using the log4net library -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="MerchantLog.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and could resolve it by exchanging
PayPal_Merchant_SDK
to 
PayPal_Core_SDK
in the configSections part.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly name is wrong in the paypal doc and samples. The config section should reference the assembly name. So "PayPal_Core_SDK" should really be "PayPalCoreSDK"

Answer (score 0):

well, after trying to get it working late into the evening yesterday, I decided to create a new mvc4 mobile web app, and only put in the paypal references etc, and low and behold, it worked, now I am not sure what is wrong with the other app, but I think it will probably be quicker to just transfer my code a cross section by section.

I just thought I would let people know, and if I get chance, I will look at the code again, as I don't like been beat :-)